# Confusion about upcasting and overloaded methods

Tags: java, casting, overloading, upcasting

Let's say, we have these two classes and one main method:

```
public class Super {
    public void f(double d){
        System.out.println("Super: f(double d)");
    }
    public void f(int i){
        System.out.println("Super: f(int i)");
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public void f(double d){
        System.out.println("Sub: f(double d)");
    }

    public void f(float f){
        System.out.println("Sub: f(float f)");
    }
}

public class M {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sub a = new Sub();
        a.f(1.5f); //output: "Sub: f(float f)"

        Super b = new Sub();
        b.f(1.5f); //output: "Sub: f(double d)"
    }
}
```

Why does the second call results in `Sub: f(double d)` and not in `Sub: f(float f)` like the first one?

When I add

```
public void f(float f) {
    System.out.println("Super: f(float f)");
}
```

to the `Super` class, the output changes to `Sub: f(float f)`.

Given this behavior, I expect the workflow looks like this:

1. As `a` is upcasted to `Super`, the class `Super` is checked for a matching method
2. Only `public void f(double d)` is found, so the float is casted to a double
3. Now the method `public void f(double d)` in the more specific class `Sub` is seen and executed

Is this correct?

Comment: Because there is no method `f(float)` available through a reference of type `Super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this behavior, note that *choosing* which method to call out of a series of overloaded methods is always performed at compile-time. However, method *dispatch* is performed at runtime.

Therefore, at compile-time, only the `double` version is visible, but it will get dispatched to the subclass's overridden version at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The method `b.f(1.5f)` is looked up at compile time. Its implementation will be the more specific one (if present) at runtime but which overloaded method is chosen is bound at compile time.

Since `b` is at least a `Super` the only conclusion that the compiler can infer is that the method will be `void f(double v)` (since `Super` doesn't have a `float` overload) so that one is chosen.

Then at runtime the implementation is the one of `Sub` class, thanks to dynamic binding.